# SQL Server 2008 EXCEPT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-except

Here is my example script:

```
SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table2
```

I'm successfully returning unique records from the left table that do not also exist in the right table. Both tables have identical schemas and for the most part identical data. The problem is that the unique id (let's call it column c1) does not match, so I need to exclude it in the EXCEPT query above. How can I return the same set of records, but with the unique IDs included?

I was thinking of using temporary tables, cursors and long WHERE statements inside the cursor, but that doesn't seem like a very elegant solution. is there another way to accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Comment: Which unique id you want to pull out if a record exists in both the table ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you take your supplied query, and simply `inner join` it with table 1 to get your 'c1' column?

```
SELECT T1.* FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN(
  SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table2
) a on a.c2=T1.c2 and a.c3=T1.c3 and a.c4=T1.c4
```

Comment: +1 because you beat me (but you want to check up your table aliases...)

Comment: matt - why scan table twice when this same result can be achieved using left outer join and scan table only once.

Comment: @rs. - I wanted to use the OP's original query since I know it already produces all the results he wants, minus the c1.

Comment: @PhilipKelley - You can edit my post to rename my tables/aliases if you desire!  I'm not too familiar with best practices, so I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong in your eyes.

Comment: @MattH, what Philip is trying to tell is that you are using wrong aliases `a.c2=T1.c2 and a.c3=T.c3 and a.c4=T.c4` should be `a.c2=T1.c2 and a.c3=T1.c3 and a.c4=T1.c4`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm also evidently blind, since i was staring at it for about 4 minutes not getting it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, A.c3, A.c4 
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 B ON A.c2 = B.C2 AND A.c3 = B.C3 AND A.c4 = B.C4
WHERE B.c1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can accomplish it using "NOT EXISTS" rather than "EXCEPT" since with "NOT EXISTS" you can specify conditions. Here's a thread that points this out: [EXCEPT vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665631/352349).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of ugly and, on large tables lacking "useful" indexes, might perform very poorly, but it will do the work:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4
 from Table1 t1
  inner join (--  Unique tuples
              SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table1
              EXCEPT
              SELECT c2, c3, c4 FROM Table2
             ) xx
   on xx.c2 = t1.c2
    and xx.c3 = t1.c3
    and xx.c5 = t1.c4
```