# Which one is faster between SQL NOT IN and EXCEPT?

Tags: sql, performance, query-performance

Testing with this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0d4c/2), it seems that EXCEPT is slower than NOT IN (with distinct), but the test data is very small.

I've tested with some big scenarios, but I would like a reference (I could not find one) that could prove to me that one is faster than another.

Thank you.

Comment: The execution plan is virtually the same except that the `EXCEPT` do a `TOP` which has by the way `0%` cost. However, that could spell the difference for bigger scenario? By the way, what difference did you see in the bigger scenario as you say?

Comment: Not exactly your question, but I saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance) earlier today based on performance of IN and EXISTS - similar logic in testing the performance could be derived from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use EXCEPT as opposed to NOT EXISTS in Transact SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662902/when-to-use-except-as-opposed-to-not-exists-in-transact-sql)