# Is Except operator computational expensive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which includes 30 records, and a smaller table has 10 records, both tables have the same schema. All I want to do is to return a table, whose records are in the big table, but not in the small table. The solution I found is to use `Except` operator. However, when I run the query, it took me about 30 mins. so I am just wondering that if `Except` is computational expensive and it took a lot of resources?

Is there any functions can replace `Except`? Thanks for any help !

Comment: 30 mins on a 30 record table? Something is wildly wrong or the table is locked.

Comment: At a very minimum you should include the query **and** [include the actual Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/1260204), you could use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and share the link in your question. Also [try to read it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759097/1260204), maybe you can figure out the performance issue(s) with your query.  Finally include the [schema DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) along with the query you are executing.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662902/when-to-use-except-as-opposed-to-not-exists-in-transact-sql#1664153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should be using `EXISTS`. It is one of the most performant operations in SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM big_table b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM small_table s
WHERE s.id = b.id)
```

Comment: I have tried that but it is not compatible with Miscrosoft SQL, right?

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro It is absolutely available in SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

`EXCEPT` is a set operator and it should be reasonably optimized.  It does remove duplicate values, so there is a bit more overhead than one might expect.

It is not so unoptimized that it would take 30 seconds on such small tables, unless you have columns whose size measures in many megabytes.  Something else might be going on -- such as network or server contention.

`EXCEPT` is a very reasonable approach.  `NOT IN` has a problem with `NULL` values and only works with one column.  `NOT EXISTS` is going to work best when you have an appropriate index.  Under some circumstances, `EXCEPT` is faster than `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to make things complicated for something so simple.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

Comment: 1. How do you know it is simple? 2. `NOT IN`/`IN` can be detrimental to performance and based on the question performance is already an issue. A better solution would be to use `NOT EXISTS` (or create an outer join and filter on that in the where clause).

Comment: `NOT IN` is easily the best performer if there is a proper Primary Key field. `NOT EXISTS` tests the entire record while `NOT IN` a single field.

Comment: That post talks about the possibility of NULLs, which is a non issue with a Primary key field. You do not have a sub-table situation like discussed there, where the comparison is Primary Key to Foreign Key. The comparison is Primary Key to Primary Key.

Comment: @SunKnight0 "NOT EXISTS tests the entire record" I don't think that is true, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Which brings me back to point 1, you (we actually) do not know if there are even primary keys specified in the schema or what the relation is between the two tables. The question is very poorly written and this answer of using `not in` makes a lot of assumptions.

Comment: @dfundako - it does not, it tests on the condition(s) specified in the `where` clause.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a different example. If the `WHERE` on `NOT EXISTS` only links by `Primary Key` the two are similar in execution, but the `NOT IN` much simpler to write.

Comment: Here is another relevant question with answer: [SQL Server IN vs. EXISTS Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065403/1260204)

Comment: @Igor: I agree that the existence of a PK is an assumption, but with lack of any other information I see no way to provide anything more useful. The `NOT EXISTS` solution makes the exact same assumption.

Comment: As for the performance based on the new link, I would think that the optimizer would perform the "SELECT ID FROM Table2" once for the entire query whereas it would have to perform `WHERE s.id = b.id` for every record. Am I missing something?