# Select item that is different in each of group by a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this sample table

```
+--------+-------------+
| DBName | Description |
+--------+-------------+
| A      | Car         |
| A      | Boat        |
| B      | Car         |
| B      | Plane       |
| C      | Car         |
| C      | Boat        |
| C      | Plane       |
+--------+-------------+
```

I want to take only Description that is not exist on every DBName and show what DBName that don't have the Description.

The Result from the query that I want

```
+--------+-------------+
| DBName | Description |
+--------+-------------+
| A      | Plane       |
| B      | Boat        |
+--------+-------------+
```

Keep in mind it will be more than just A,B,C on DBName.

Comment: Is there a lookup table that contains all possible descriptions?

Comment: You could try distinct on description and assume it as master data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting issue.  Here are a couple of options for solving.  There's discussions around these techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662902/when-to-use-except-as-opposed-to-not-exists-in-transact-sql), along with a few suggestions of other routes for handling scenarios such as this.

---

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fadb/1)

```
select DBName, Description
from (
    select DBName, Description
    from (select distinct DBName from demo) a
    cross join (select distinct Description from demo) b
) c
except
select DbName, Description from demo
```

This solution works by fetching every possible combination (via cross join of distinct values for each column), then excluding all those which already exist via the `except` clause.

---

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fadb/6)

```
select [each].DBName, missing.Description
from (select distinct DBName from demo) [each]
cross join (select distinct Description from demo) [missing]
where not exists 
(
  select top 1 1
  from demo [exists]
  where [exists].DbName = [each].DBName
  and [exists].Description = [missing].Description
)
```

This solution is the same as the above, only instead of the `except` cluase we use `where not exists` to remove existing combos.

Comment: The Second query(where not exists) return C Boat which is incorrect, the first query is working for me

Comment: Thanks @AdinugrahaTawaqal.  FYI: The second query should work; only I made a mistake with the demo data (populated `C, Car` twice instead of including `C, Boat`).  Tweaking the SQL Fiddle link now...

Comment: No Problem, I should be the one saying Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should have a master list of data. In case you do not you should deriv3 it from the data and then put checks against them like below:

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/33828/2)

```
select 
masterlistDbname.Dbname,
masterlistDesc.Description 
from
(
    select distinct Description from yourtable
) masterlistDesc
cross join
(
    select distinct Dbname from yourtable
) masterlistDbname
left join
yourtable t1 
on t1.Dbname = masterlistDbname.Dbname
and t1.Description = masterlistDesc.Description 
where t1.Dbname is NULL
```

Comment: What I try to solve with this is I have master data on multiple database, same structure different contents. I want to make the master data description uniform or at least try to point out differences between database. Each database is it's own company and I work in holding Company.

Answer (score 0):

use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   yourtable x
           WHERE  x.Description = t.Description 
           AND    x.DBName     <> t.DBName 
       )
```

Comment: There's a slight issue in that this will only return records from `yourtable`; so won't fulfil the task of selecting those records which don't exist in that table as they don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

you should throw little more Sample data.

Try this,

```
create table #test(DBName varchar(50),Descriptions varchar(50) )

insert into #test VALUES
('A','Car')        
,('A','Boat')       
,('B','Car')        
,('B','Plane')      
,('C','Car')        
,('C','Boat')       
,('C','Plane')      

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY DBName ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn1
    FROM #test
    )
SELECT t.DBName
    ,t1.Descriptions
FROM cte t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Descriptions
    FROM cte t1
    WHERE t1.rn > t.rn
        AND t.Descriptions <> t1.Descriptions
        AND t.dbname <> t1.dbname
    ORDER BY t1.rn
    ) t1
WHERE t.rn1 = 1



drop table #test
```